# Activity with fragments does not resize when the keyboard opens

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments

In my main activity there is a `RelativeLayout` that has 2 childs:

- An `ImageView` which serves as the background
- A `LinearLayout` that has 2 fragment containers

## activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:src="@drawable/bg_image" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ContainerA"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
        
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ContainerB"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/background_gray"
            android:orientation="vertical" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Container A simply shows a fragment that doesn't change.
However, Container B holds a fragment that does change depending on user clicks.

Container B changes in 2 ways:

- It can expand (from a height of about 70% to full height).
- It changes fragments.

One of the fragments Container B can hold is a form, which contains `EditText`s and other views.

My problem is that I can't get the activity to resize when the keyboard is open.
I set `adjustResize` in the manifest file and my theme is not a fullscreen theme (it is apparently a cause for this problem). I also tried to edit the views, add `ScrollViews` but absolutely nothing worked.

The theme I'm using for this activity is the light theme with the dark actionbar from the `AppCompat` library. I only edited the theme to allow an overlay actionbar. This is **not** the problem as I've already tried removing those edits to no avail.

**[Here's a link to the form layout](http://pastebin.com/wvkm57wP)**

**TL;DR** `adjustResize` / `adjustPan` do not work for me. Searched, tried various solutions, nothing worked. My question is; what is the cause for this in my case?

## Update: AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" ...>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application ... android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenSize" android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/OverlayActionBarTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"  />
        <activity android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Update 2:**
I created a completely new app, added my form layout as the main layout, and tested whether the problem was in the layout itself. Turns out it is, as even on this newly created app it doesn't seem to resize.

As stated above, the link to the layout can be found **[Here](http://pastebin.com/wvkm57wP)**

**Update 3:**
I managed to make it work on the new application by surrounding the whole layout with a `ScrollView`. I couldn't replicate the same effect in the original app for some reason... still trying to figure out why.

Comment: can you post of an image what it look like

Comment: @xTCx, Have you tried **scrollviews** to both **main activity** and **fragment B's XML**???

Comment: please remove the complexity of LinearLayout ( means you are using multiple level of LinearLayout ) instead of that you can use RelativeLayout also

Answer (score 31, accepted):

When the soft keyboard appears on the screen, the amount of space available for the application's UI reduces. The system makes decision on how to organize the available space between the application's UI and soft keyboard.

- If the window content contains `ListView`, `ScrollView`, the application's window is resized provided all the content is visible.
- If re-sizing is not feasible, `pan and scan` approach is used, which simply involves scrolling the application's window so that the currently focused view is visible.

Since your layout does not contain any `ListView`, `ScrollView`, re-sizing is ruled out.

The window's root view is a `FrameLayout` to which you were originally adding `LinearLayout`. Since `LinearLayout` does not support scrolling, `pan and scan` approach is also ruled out. Hence wrapping the layout inside ScrollView solves the scrolling issue.

You can refer [Android Developers blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html) for more details.

**Update 1:**

OP was able to solve the issue, as indicated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25400637/2083078). The issue was happening due to one fragment overlaying another fragment after animation and the parent of these `Fragment`'s was a `LinearLayout`. For overlay purpose, you need to use `RelativeLayout` or `FrameLayout` only.

Comment: Hi, thank you for commenting. This is actually pretty close to the real 'solution' please read my answer below and edit yours so I can mark it as accepted! :)

Comment: This was such a detailed explanation that I decided to try out and wrap my fragment inside a nested scroll view and it fixed my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

**You can use this code in your Fragment also**

This code provide help for resize view

```
public static class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Dialog layout inflater code
    // getDialog() need to be called only after onCreateDialog(), which is invoked between onCreate() and onCreateView(). 
      getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN |     WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
   // return view code
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me in my `Fragment`, thank you!

Comment: Worked for me for fragment inside Viewpager.

Answer (score 13):

To change the mode to “resize” at the following statement to your activity in “AndroidManifest.xml”.

> ```
>  <activity android:name=".ActivityName"
>         android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
> ```

and please remove the complexity of LinearLayout ( means you are using multiple level of LinearLayout ) instead of that you can use RelativeLayout also .. using this you can easily set Layout as you want .. try it that also hope your problem may rectifier

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 8):

Use this in onCreateDialog in BottomSheetFragment / Dailogfragment

```
KeyboardUtil(getActivity(), view);
```

or

For fragment use

```
new KeyboardUtil(this, findViewById(R.id.fragment_container));
```

by using this Util class

https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/blob/aa9136fb4f5b3a80460fe5f47213985026d20c88/library/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/materialdrawer/util/KeyboardUtil.java

Credit:Mikepenz

Comment: Nothing helped but at last this one help a lot

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! This is the only thing that works!

Comment: can scroll conente but it doesn't jump automaticly

Answer (score 6):

use this line in your manifest file against your activity in which you want your result
hope it will help you

```
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateAlwaysHidden"
```

like

```
  <activity
            android:name="com.android.youractivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateAlwaysHidden" />
```

Answer (score 6):

Turns out my problem was caused by a completely unexpected source.

What happened is that I used a `LinearLayout` as the parent of my two fragment containers.
Then, in my expanding animation I raised the bottom container to overlap the other one.

I don't really know **why** but since `LinearLayout` is not supposed to hold overlapping children, switching to a `RelativeLayout` or a `FrameLayout` immediately solved the issue.

Since this cause might not be apparent from the code I posted, I do want to apologize for the lack of information, and will credit the most detailed answer as the best one.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line of code in DialogFragment Oncreateview below R.layout.layout_ui

```
getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN |     WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```