# how to disable image resize while if i open keyboard in device?

Tags: android, keyboard, imageview

I am working on fragment.so in my first page image will display fine as per below.

[image]

after i did open second fragment and there i enter some text so, keyboard open in device.when i came back from second fragment to first fragment i seen my above image will re-sized and look like below image.

[image]

for image display i used dynamically height and width adjustment as square.

Code snippet:

```
 ViewTreeObserver vto = img_Headimage.getViewTreeObserver();
            vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
                public boolean onPreDraw() {
                    int Height = img_Headimage.getMeasuredHeight();
                    int Width = img_Headimage.getMeasuredWidth();
                   img_Headimage.getLayoutParams().width=Height;
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

hows happened this kind of issue .can anybody give idea?

***Your answer would be appreciated.***

Comment: Use scaleType="fixXY" as a property for your imageview in xml.

Comment: Upload some code. What is the fragments hierarchy?

Comment: @user5716019 issue occure after once i open keyboard in second fragment then.

Comment: hierarchy like 1st fragment already opened after i will open second fragment above first fragment.

Comment: Issue might because of  you are using dynamically height and width adjustment as square. Will you please, upload your code ?

Comment: I put some code but please try to understand this issue occurred after keyboard open.

Comment: That means, If you don't open keyboard in second fragment and come back to first fragment, there is no any issue. Is it so ?

Comment: exactly it works fine if i didn't open keyboard in second fragment.

Comment: Then this might helps you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25303285/activity-with-fragments-does-not-resize-when-the-keyboard-opens

Comment: @user5716019 thank you bro.your link help to me lot.

Comment: will you please upvote it.. wc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution of above question:

set below lines in manifest current activity or fragment container activity.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateAlwaysHidden"
```