# Edittext is hidden if softkeyboard is opened in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-tabhost, android-softkeyboard

First of all please don't make it duplicate as all other related post doesn't help!

I have a combination of `Tab bar` and a `fragment` having form when I reached onto bottom then all bottom content under keyboard are not visible. Under keyboard there are 3-4 `Edit Text` which are gaining focus but don't come above the keyboard when I type something.

The problem is following xml attribute:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan"
```

in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
</activity>
```

I have to put this as I don't want `Tab bar` to come above keyboard.
Please help!

Comment: did you tried setting it programmatically in your fragment?

Comment: @VivekMishra Yes I tried it : i.e. context.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);

Comment: check accepted answer from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25303285/activity-with-fragments-does-not-resize-when-the-keyboard-opens

Comment: Add your layout content in ScrollView and try again. It will surely help you