# In Fragment Activity when soft keyboard appears screen doesn't resize

Tags: java, android

I am developing an android app. In this app my main activity has a container to host fragment activity. In my fragment activity I have some editText fields. When I am clicks on one of edit field soft keyboard appears but screen doesn't resize according to current situation. I have tried some suggestions like

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

and

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

I am testing at a device which runs MarshMallow OS. What should I do know.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21201569/android-resize-only-parts-of-view-with-soft-keyboard-on-screen
This might help you...

Comment: Nop, It doesn't help me.

Comment: Any other suggestion for adjusting screen size when dealing with Fragment activity

Comment: Have you put scrollview inside your layout? if no then put whole layout inside scroll view with height as match parent and define android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" inside manifest....

Comment: Which layout should be in scrollview? Fragment or Main?

Comment: Obviously fragment layout...

Comment: It's already in Scroll view. It's a registration form, so it's lengthy and I have put it in scrollview.

Comment: This might help you bro...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25303285/activity-with-fragments-does-not-resize-when-the-keyboard-opens